# An error occurred while using the Python magic library at Docker & Github Action. "E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic'"

Tags: python, docker, github-actions

**Issue Description:**
Running a Python project using the `python-magic` library within a Docker container on Windows 10 OS results in the error "Module magic not found."

**Proposed Fix:**
Initially, changing the dependency from `python-magic` to `python-magic-bin` resolved the issue in the local environment. However, when running the project in a Docker container, the same error resurfaced unexpectedly.

**Dockerfile Content:**

```
# Dockerfile for API service
FROM python:3.11.0 as base

# Dependencies installations
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    poppler-utils \
    tesseract-ocr \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libmagic1 \
    python3-magic

# Non-root user setup
RUN groupadd --gid 1000 user && adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --uid 1000 --gid 1000 user
WORKDIR /home/user
USER user

# Development stage setup
FROM base as dev
USER root
COPY --chown=user:user ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY --chown=user:user ./src /home/user/src
COPY --chown=user:user ./test /home/user/test
COPY --chown=user:user .env /home/user/.env
USER user
CMD ["python", "-m", "uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000", "--reload", "--env-file", "/home/user/.env"]

# Test stage setup
FROM base as test
COPY --chown=user:user ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
USER root
COPY --chown=user:user ./src /home/user/src
COPY --chown=user:user ./test /home/user/test
RUN mkdir /home/user/.mypy_cache && chown user:user -R /home/user/.mypy_cache
RUN pip install pytest
CMD ["pytest"]
USER user

# Default target stage
FROM dev
```

**Current Challenge:**
The error "Module magic not found" persists when running the project in a Docker container despite changing the library dependency. Seeking insights or suggestions to overcome this issue. Your thoughts?

Regards

Comment: The module would need to be installed inside the docker container.  Is it?

Comment: Docker using requirements.txt file to install the module.

Comment: Show us the dockerfile, and show us the full error message.

Comment: Please (re)read ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly, because your post doesn't contain nearly enough information right now for people to tell what went wrong, and so they can't help you fix that.